# Crosswalk in Android - XWalkView - Set HTTP headers

Tags: android-webview, crosswalk-runtime

I am new to Crosswalk. So far I have embedded it using Android Studio and can load a webpage via `XWalkView.load(url,null)`
However I also need to pass POST data via the HTTP Headers.
With the native Android WebView I'd pass data in the second parameter as `WebView.loadUrl(url,additionalHttpHeaders)`

How can I achieve the same in my Crosswalk implementation?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Nope I could not find a solution for this. I ended up embedding the code on the client.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I achieved this, I think it's a new feature on the latest versions, I used CrossWalk WebView 19.49.514.0.
There's a new method wich accepts a third parameter, like the classic WebView.
Example:

```
XWalkView xwView=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwView);
Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
extraHeaders.put("Referer","http://www.myref.com/");
xwView.load("http://headerscheck.byethost24.com/headers.php",null,extraHeaders);
```